# Where to get JWT for RequestAuthentication in Istio

Tags: authentication, kubernetes, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, istio

### Context

I am currently in the process of setting up AuthN and AuthZ for Istio. I will have to consume an (external) OIDC Identity Provider. I know that Istio provides RequestAuthentication and AuthorizationPolicies. I already have them set up:

- My RequestAuthentication is already able to validate Requests.
- Second my AuthorizationPolicy is also enabled using a Custom action with a OPA policy checking for access.

For reference I use Istio 1.19.

### Question

To my question: I see how I can validate and check my requests if they *already have* a JWT & Access token. I don't quite get how to populate my request with these tokens.

I have already ruled out a few options:

- Using a custom AuthorizationPolicy with oauth2-proxy. This is not possible, because only one `Custom` action is currently supported by Istio.
- Using a basic Nginx Ingress. We want to use the full featureset of the Istio Gateway, using an k8s Ingress would conflict with this.

Basically I just want a way of initiating an OIDC flow (authN) and do the authZ separately.

Thanks for any help
Cheers